# pull instead of fetch - accidentally merged remote master into local branch

Tags: git

I just did `git pull` instead of `git fetch`. I was in a local branch that I didn't want to merge with `origin/master`. Moreover, I had some uncommited changes.

Now my staging area is full of changes from `origin/master` I'd like to revert, but if I unstage them, they will mix with my uncommited changes in unstaged.

How can I remedy this situation?

Comment: Not really a solution to your problem, but I do have a useful tip: Before doing anything even remotely risky, "checkpoint" your current state by doing "git branch foo". Now, no matter *what* goes wrong, you can always get back to where you were. That trick, plus having a good tree visualizer like gitg or gitx has made git 10x easier for me to use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am assuming that the whole mess of changes are due to conflicts from your merge.  What I would suggest to do is.

1. Commit the changes from the merge (finishing it).  You will end up with a commit for now this is temporary (DO NOT PUSH!!!)
2. `git stash` your uncommitted changes so that we don't lose them.
3. `git log -3`, this will show your merge commit along with 2 previous commits.  In the merge commit you will see 2 SHAS.  One is the latest commit from origin/master and the other the last commit on your branch.
4. `git reset --hard <SHA of YOUR last commit>` This will reset your branch to before you merged and get rid of all the commits/changes that you brought in from master.
5. `git stash pop` to get your uncommitted changes back on to your branch.

Because your changes are all on your local branch, you can modify history to get things back to a state that you want without any problems.  If there are any staged files that you actually want do a `git reset -- <filenames>` to unstage them and then follow the above steps.

Answer (score 3):

I think you probably want `git merge --abort` .
From the documentation:

> Abort the current conflict resolution process, and try to reconstruct the pre-merge state.
>
> If there were uncommitted worktree changes present when the merge started, git merge --abort will in some cases be unable to reconstruct these changes. It is therefore recommended to always commit or stash your changes before running git merge.

http://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge

Answer (score 1):

I have TortoiseGit to manage my git repos and it's pretty convenient.
these are the steps that I'd do (using TortoiseGit)
- first stash your changes (TortoiseGit->Stash) and name appropriately, so all your uncommitted changes are saved onto the stash

- second, (right click in your repo->TortoiseGit) "Show Log" and that will bring up all the change logs, (assuming you know where you were before the merge - maybe you had some commits already done) look for it, and right click on that change log, say "reset to this commit" in the next section choose "Hard Reset" this will remove all the commits from the selected commit to top and also remove the changes.
- re apply your stash (right click, TortoiseGit->Stash) and then apply the stash you saved earlier

Comment: Won't stashing also save the changes caused by the merge?

Comment: @prasopes you are correct `git stash` will also stash the staged files.  That is why you will actually need to commit them before stashing and then hard reset to your commit.

Comment: well, stashing will not save changes caused by merge, the thing that I assumed was there are no conflicts and conflict resolutions made, else stashing should save modifications that are not committed.
else what @Schleis says is right, commit the merge (if there were conflicts and then resolved)

Comment: also, just another thing that might be really helpful is stopping from pushing changes to the wrong git repos by mistake -
- edit ./.git.config,
- look for the remote that you definitely do not want to push to
- add these lines at the end for each remote you want to avoid.
  push = null
 pushurl = no_push

Answer (score -1):

You can just revert the merge step and it will append a new commit that undoes all the file changes from the merge

```
$ git revert <merge_commit_hash>
```

If you do a `$ git log --graph --oneline` you'll have to look for the commit that says something like:  "Merge branch "foo" of "remote_x" blah blah"

Comment: This will cause issues when the OP wants to actually merge with master

Comment: Why would it?  You can do the exact same merge again, and if you want to revert that again you can do so.  Revert will do this safely because it appends a new commit you're thinking about reset.

Comment: No revert is the command.  In order to not stomp all over the changes from master, you now have to do another revert and now the history is messy with the revert of a revert.  Plus if there are any more changes on master, you are now dealing with fixing the merge conflicts of those changes....  Rather than just having a clean merge with only your changes.